# Insert Horizontal Line in Word Document with Power Shell

Tags: powershell, scripting, ms-word

Is there a way to insert a horizontal line within a Power Shell generated MS Word document?  If so, what is the code needed to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Document = "c:\temp\tralala.doc" #Must exist

$Word = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $true
$ExistingDoc = $Word.Documents.Open($Document)
$ExistingDoc.Shapes.AddLine(0,0,1000,1000)
$ExistingDoc.Save()
$Word.Quit()
```

`WordDocument.Shapes.AddLine(BeginX, BeginY, EndX, EndY, Anchor)` is the call drawing the line where
BeginX, BeginY are the position (in points) of the line's starting point, 
relative to the anchor. 
EndX, EndY   are the position (in points) of the line's end point, relative to the anchor. 
If anchor is omitted, the line is positioned relative to the top and left edges of the page.